# Analyticity of the semigroup on unimodular Lie group generated by the sublaplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, lie-groups, semigroup-of-operators

Let $G$ a connected unimodular Lie group, endowed with Haar measure $X={X_1,\cdots,X_k}$ a Hörmander system of left-invariant vector fields. The sublaplacian $\Delta = - \sum_{i=1}^k X_i^2$ generates a symmetric Markovian semigroup $H_t$ and $H_t$ admits a right convolution kernel $h_t$ such that
$$H_tf(x) = \int_G h_t(y^{-1}x) f(y)dy. $$

For Lie groups G with exponential growth, i.e., there exists $D \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $V (t) \approx t^D$, $t> 1$ ( $V(t)$ is the Haar measure of ball of radius $t$), is shown in Lemma VIII 2.5 of [Analysis and Geometry on Groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/analysis-and-geometry-on-groups/21C53A64A5D9AAE274A01BF897FBC052)

**Lemma VIII 2.5.** For every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \geq 1$, there exists $C_m$ such that
$$ || \left( \dfrac{\partial}{ \partial t} \right)^m h_t(\cdot) \exp(\alpha \rho(\cdot)) ||_p \leq C_mt^{-m} V(\sqrt{t})^{-1/p} e^{C_m \alpha^2 t}, \quad \alpha>0, t>0.  $$

The following corollary that results from this Lemma, gives the analyticity of the semigroup in $L^1:$

**VIII.2.6 Corollary** The semigroup $(H_t)_{t>0}$ is bounded analytic on $L^1$ when G has polynomial growth.

The proof of Corollary follows from Lemma VIII 2.5. by noting that: $||  \dfrac{\partial h_t}{ \partial t}  ||_1 \leq C t^{-1}. $

I have two questions, first, I'm not sure what criterion the author used to say that the semigroup is analytic based on the calculation of the norm of the derivative of the semigroup in $L^1$, it seems to me that he used Theorem 5.2 (d) from section 2.5 from [Pazy's](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-5561-1) book, a condition like $||A H_t || \leq Ct^{-1}$, where $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of $H_t$, but you need to know more about the semigroup, that is, that it is of class $C_0$, differentiable and $0 \in spec(A)$ .

Second, and more interesting, would the semigroup be analytic also in $L^p$, $p>1$? What would be the problem in $L^p$ to guarantee analyticity? It is not possible to try to do a calculation of the same type as the Lemma VIII 2.5.?

Comment: Analyticity on $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$ is actually easier. It's a result of Stein (you can find it in Davies' book on heat kernels) that any $C_0$-semigroup that's symmetric on $L^2$ and bounded on $L^1$ is analytic on $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$. Analyticity on $L^1$ on the other hand can fail in this situation. For example, that happens for the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup on $L^1(\mathbb R^d,\gamma_d)$, where $\gamma_d$ is the standard Gaussian measure.

Comment: Hi @MaoWao , thanks for giving an answer. I was looking for this result in Davies' book and didn't find it, is it written in the terms you described? Or do you need to interpret some other result to reach this conclusion?

Comment: Sorry, I was on my phone and did not have the reference ready. It's Theorem 1.4.2 in Davies' book.